# Handle on success event with npm package request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I have a node.js app that scrapes informations from a website. I'm using npm packages request and cheerio and the scraping works fine but I want to do something else when the request function is done. Here's some code:
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var extractor = require("./extractor");
console.log(extractor('http://www.example.com'));
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

extractor.js (all the fun)

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var Extractor = function(url) {
    var games = [];
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('tr.game').each(function(i, v){
                var game = { /* many attributes */ };
                games.push(game);
            });
        }
    });
    this.extractedGames = games;
};
module.exports = function(url) {
    return new Extractor(url);
};
```

Eventually when I run this it shows `{ extractedGames: [] }` that is because the output was printed before the request treatment was over. So I want to add an on success event to extracedGames attribute when the request job is over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself ! I hope this could help people in the future (though I felt like a complete noob)
The trick was to emit an event and handle it later.

```
var express = require('express');
var extractor = require("./extractor");
extractor('http://www.example.com');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

I removed `console.log(extractor('http://www.example.com'))` because this would run before the request job is done. So I moved it to the event handling function.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var Emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var extractEmitter = new Emitter();
extractEmitter.on('extracted', function(extractedGames){
    console.log(extractedGames);
});
var Extractor = function(url) {
    var games = [];
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('tr.game').each(function(i, v){
                var game = { /* many attributes */ };
                games.push(game);
            });
            extractEmitter.emit('extracted', games);
        }
    });
    this.extractedGames = games;
};
module.exports = function(url) {
    return new Extractor(url);
};
```